# How to fetch the custom header viz AO-7DEABF from the response in Gatling tool

Tags: api, rest, gatling

I am looking for the syntax to fetch custom headers from the response.

I am using Gatling tool for performance testing. I could find syntax's for JAVA and other language's, however, those are not working with the Gatling syntax.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some code, you have already tried to get sufficient help.

Comment: header RetriveHeaders[] = response.getAllHeaders(),
val CustomHeadere = "$..response.getFirstHeader("AO-7DEABF")".getValue(),

Comment: Above is the code snippet i tried in my gatling "Test Step Creation", I have received "Invalid literal number" and "expected string bu found ]" errors.